# TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not MagicMock

Tags: python, exception, mocking

I want to test the exception handling in my code:

```
def test_get_mails__exception_in_search(self):
    with mock.patch('imaplib.IMAP4', autospec=True) as imap_mock:
        imap_mock.return_value.create.return_value = ('OK', [''])
        imap_mock.return_value.search.side_effect=imap_mock.error
        self.get_mails()
```

But the mock library raises:

```
TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, 
not MagicMock
```

How can I test my code: I want `imaplib.search` to raise `imaplib.error`

Comment: Including the *full* traceback would make it much easier to give you an answer beyond *don't ask me why*. I can probably tell you why.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution:

```
    with mock.patch('imaplib.IMAP4', autospec=True) as imap_mock:
        imap_mock.error=Exception # <----    This is needed, don't ask me why
        imap_mock.return_value.create.return_value = ('OK', [''])
        imap_mock.return_value.search.side_effect=imap_mock.error
        self.get_mails()
```

Comment: Sounds like you really should have used `imap_mock.return_value.search.side_effect = Exception` then.

Comment: Or rather, `imap_mock.return_value.search.side_effect = Exception('Some message')`, to be more precise.